# Tasks ToDo app with .NET api on server side

Tags: task

Is there any ToDo app that have .NET api for server side adding tasks.
Since there is no API for Goggle Tasks, I am looking for something that I can feed
from my own custom Tasking Web App.
Here in our company We are using our custom madded Web App for tasking and organizing our work.That app is written in .NET with C#. Now I looking for some Android apps for tasking which is able to on server side receive task by .NET and C# api. 
[Remeber The Milk](http://www.rememberthemilk.com/) looks nice and have [IronCow](http://ironcow.codeplex.com/) as API but that app is commercial for android devices.
Is there others similar services as Rember The Milk that have this both, C# api for server side adding tasks and good looking Android client

Comment: Most people who *use* such apps are not going to be aware of any APIs. This looks to me like it would be better served on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you missed the Google I/O [announcement](http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2011/05/getting-organized-with-tasks-api.html), now there **is** an [API](http://code.google.com/apis/tasks/) for Google Tasks, with [.NET](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/) and [Android/Java](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/) support.